# How can I select multiple pictures using change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select multiple pictures. Currently I'm able to get pictures single-single but I want to get multiple. How can I do that?

What I tried:

```js
 $(function() {
                $(document).on('change', '.caFileBtn', function() {
                    console.log(imagePath);
                    var files = this.files
                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        var file = files[i];
                        var imagePath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    }
                    var imageElement = `
    <div>
    <img src="${imagePath}" />
    </div>
`;
                    $('.ca-photos-area').show();
                    $('.ca-photos-area').prepend(imageElement);

                    $(this).val('');
                });

            });
```

```css
  .ca-photos-area {
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .ca-photos-area img {
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            <input type="file" Multiple="Multiple" class="caFileBtn" />
            <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="ca-photos-area mt-3">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While html tags and attributes are case-insensitive it's best practice to use lowercase. Though, attribute values are case-sensitive. So, you must define `multiple` in lowercase:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="caFileBtn" />
<!-- Must be in lowercase --- ^^ -->
<!-- Otherwise, it's still single type -->
```

Or, you could also have defined attribute only:

```
<input type="file" multiple class="caFileBtn" />
```

The above answer seems to be wrong in the case of multiple attribute as it accepts boolean and using it case-insensitive also meant to be multiple.

Here's the working javascript code that will select all selected images:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.caFileBtn', function() {
        console.log(imagePath);
        var files = this.files
        var imageElement = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           var file = files[i];
           var imagePath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           imageElement.push( `
            <div>
              <img src="${imagePath}" />
            </div>`);
        }   
       for (var i=0; i<imageElement.length; i++){
         $('.ca-photos-area').prepend(imageElement[i]);
       }
       $('.ca-photos-area').show();
       $(this).val('');
  });
});
```

Comment: are you still able to select single file only?

Comment: no bro i'm able to select multiple file & its working also earlier but only i'm able to select multiple files and get only one. I want to get multiple files at a time.

Comment: let me check again.

Comment: You have image element outside the for loop

Comment: Thanks you so much @Bhojendra Rauniyar for your efforts, its working fine now.

Comment: You could also use just single for loop where you could have prepend the image inside that loop itself. But I have separated it as if you'll do something else with them.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

The majority of the statements within handler were outside the `for` loop. BTW I removed the reset statement: `$(this).val('')` because the tag would always display: *"no files selected..."* whether there were files selected or not. Without the reset you get a list of the file names selected.

#### Demo

```js
$('.caFileBtn').on('change', function() {

  const self = $(this)[0];
  const files = self.files;
  let imagePath, imageTag;

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];
    imagePath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    imageTag = `<figure><img src="${imagePath}"></figure>`;
    $('.ca-photos-area').prepend(imageTag);
  }
});
```

```css
.ca-photos-area {
  display: flex;
}

.ca-photos-area img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
  <input class="caFileBtn" type="file" multiple="multiple">
  <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
</label>

<section class="col-md-12">
  <article class="ca-photos-area mt-3"></article>
</section>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```